# How do I make this field unique?

Tags: joomla, unique-key, joomla-community-builder

I am sorry if this question already exist. I searched but could not find the answer myself.

I am creating a website, people need to register. But I have a specific field which people have to fill in. They have that code themselves so they have to fill it in when they register.

But I want this field to be unique. So in other words, if person A registered with this code, than no one else can use this code to register.

This is my code:

```
/(?i)^([A-Z0-9]{2}+7[A-Z0-9]{2}+[2,6,J])*$/
```

as example this should be the outcome: 
`xx7xx2` or
`xx7xx6` or
`xx7xxJ`

My followup question is: as you can see, I ignored caps. But I want the outcome to be caps. so if people write `xx7xx2` than the result should be `XX7XX2`.

Comment: where would you store these codes? is it a relational database? if so, use a primary key, problem solved

Comment: these codes are stored in my joomla community builder. sorry for being newb but it is my first time.

Comment: it is not relational database if im correct. I can explain more specific.

Comment: people play a game where there is no communication. so they are going to use my website to communicate with eachother. But each user has a unique game code. and that is what I want. each user with an unique code. No duplicates allowed. and on top of that... caps.

Comment: why do not generate the code as time stamp, then hash it using md5 or whatever. the time stamp is unique unless in the very unlikely event of two persons join the game at the very exact time

Comment: I dont mind what to do. As long as the result is: person A use code xx7xx2 at registration. outcome will be XX7XX2. person B wants to use code xx7xx2 but he can't because its already in use. will that work with that time stamp? and if it does, how do I do that in joomla? or do I need to do this in the cpanel? if in cpanel, what code must I use?

Comment: my question again, why do you want the user to enter the code? why would not you generate the code at the time of joining the game from the server side and then assign that code to the new player

Comment: because this code is needed when people want to trade their items in-game. This code is also shown on their profile. sorry for the late response

Comment: Do you see your username in stackoverflow?it is user###### did you enter that number? It is unique by the way, the website has generated for you.  so, you can use cookie to attach it to user session, this way, read the cookie and you dont need the user to enter it

Comment: I dont know what ideas you have but if you dont have an answer than say you dont know. All i want is this field to be unique and all caps. nothing more or less. There are maybe 100 other possiblities but like I said. All I want is people to fill this field at registration. if a person does than that number must be unique so no one else can register with the same code. Also the output must be in caps too. if you know how to do this let me know and if you dont let me know too. Im not looking for a diffrent solution and not asking for sugestions. Im asking for a solution at my idea. pls help

Comment: Well, to end this long discussion, i would  say sorry, i don't know

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom JFormRule that follows the basic pattern of username for enforcing uniqueness.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/form/rule/username.php